# How to solve this challenge using a FIFO stack?

Tags: c#, stack

I'm using a portion of C# code from [Sanjit Prasad](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-after-processing-backspace-characters/) to solve the challenge of processing backspaces in a given string of words. The new challenge is to process the left-arrow-key and right-arrow-key in combination with backspaces, reflecting a "corrector" for typos in writing.

The following string represents the problem and solution for the first challenge using a FIFO stack (credits to Sanjit Prasad):

```
string: thiss# is a txt##ext with some typos
expected result: this is a text with some typos
```

This is the code to generate the expected result:

```
static String finalAnswer(String S)  
{  
 Stack<Char> q = new Stack<Char>();  

 for (int i = 0; i < S.Length; ++i)  
 {  
  if (S[i] != '#') q.Push(S[i]);  
  else if (q.Count!=0) q.Pop();  
 }  

 String ans = "";  

 while (q.Count!=0) 
 {  
  ans += q.Pop();  
 }  

 String answer = ""; 

 for(int j = ans.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
 { 
  answer += ans[j]; 
 } 
 return answer;  
}
```

That code works great, now, the challenge is to process the following string:

```
string: ths#is is an te\\\#///xt wit some\\\\\h///// tpos###ypos
expected result: this is a text with some typos
```

In the above string, the character "\" represents a left arrow key pressed, and "/" a right arrow key pressed.

Thank you so much for all your comments, this is my very first question in Stackoverflow, I would like to know an approach to solve the this challenge.

Comment: I can think of a solution to do this with two stacks, but how to do with one is escaping me. Are you only allowed one stack?

Comment: Hi @DetectivePikachu, no matter how, the idea is to solve the challenge, thank you!

Comment: Add another stack for the chars popped off the result when a back slash is processed. Similarly, when a forward slash is processed, you'll pop from it to push them back on the result stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that gets the job done, but will need some checks for edge cases and some  more error checks.

```
        static string GenerateUpdatedString(string strInput)
        {
            var stringStack = new Stack<char>();//holds the string as it is read from the input
            var workingStack = new Stack<char>();//hold chars when going back to fix typos

            char poppedChar;

            foreach (var ch in strInput)
            {
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case '\\':
                        {
                            PushAndPopCharacters(workingStack, stringStack);
                            break;
                        }
                    case '/':
                        {
                            PushAndPopCharacters(stringStack, workingStack);
                            break;
                        }
                    case '#':
                        {
                            stringStack.TryPop(out poppedChar);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        stringStack.Push(ch);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return new string(stringStack.Reverse().ToArray());
        }

        static void PushAndPopCharacters(Stack<char> stackToPush, Stack<char> stackToPop)
        {
            char poppedChar;
            if (stackToPop.TryPop(out poppedChar))
            {
                stackToPush.Push(poppedChar);
            }
        }
```

Usage

```
            var result = GenerateUpdatedString
                          (@"ths#is is an te\\\#///xt wit some\\\\\h///// tpos###ypos");
```